# Convert object list to another object list even they are not same type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, object, 3-tier

I want to be separate between ViewModel and Mode(Data Access Object Or Data Members). Please see below.

Major DAO

```
Public Class Major

       Public MajorID as Integer
       Public MajorName as String

End Class
```

Major VM

```
Public Class MajorVM

       Public Major as Major

End Class
```

But Major View Model take a reference for major. In this case, I would like to convert major object to majorvm object list. Please see below.

```
Dim MajorList as list(of Major) = GetAllMajorList()
Dim MajorVMList as List(of MajorVM)

MajorVMList = MajorList
```

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim MajorVMList as New List(of MajorVM)

For each item as Major in MajorList 

 Dim m as new Major
 Major.MajorID = item.MajorID
 Major.MajorName = item.MajorName

 MajorVMList.Add(Major)


Next
```

Comment: hi dude. Is there another short form? Like this.  TryCast(CObj(MajorDAL.GetAll), List(Of MajorVM)). Thanks.